# How to solve this first order difference equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this first order difference equation:

$x_{t+1}=1+\alpha\beta(1-{1\over x_t})$

$t=1,2,\dots,T$

$x_0> 0$ ; $x_T=0$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: @Rol Hi. I am sorry i made an error in posting the question. $x_0>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there are rational expressions involved, so write $x_k=\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ and use the freedom of (reverse) cancellation to derive the recursion
$$
q_{k+1}=p_k\\
p_{k+1}=(1+αβ)q_k-αβp_k
$$
This now is a linear system with characteristic equation
$$
0=λ(λ+αβ)-(1+αβ)=(λ-1)(λ+1+αβ)
$$
etc...